# Diferença na passagem do tipo de dado por referência

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, passagem-por-referência

Olá, estou com dúvida em relação a como passar determinado dado por referência.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

mostra_frase(char *frase){
    printf("\nFrase digitada %s\n", frase);
}

void mostra_numero (int *numero){
    printf("Numero digitado %i", *numero);
}

int main(){
    char frase[100];
    int numero;

    printf("Digite uma frase\n");
    gets(frase);

    printf("Digite um numero\n");
    scanf("%i", &numero);

    mostra_frase(frase);
    mostra_numero(&numero);     
}
```

Minha dúvida é:
Por que na passagem por referencia da frase utilizando gets não preciso passar o &endereço de memória e na passagem de um número sim ?

Comment: Porque o nome de um array na realidade se refere ao endereço do primeiro elemento desse array.

Comment: O ponteiro em `mostra_numero()` é completamente desnecessário. `gets(0` não deveria ser usada mais.